# Do i have to provide a Realm Migration when only adding new Fields?

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

In theory simply adding new fields could work without migrating, those fields would just be null on all existing objects. Does Realm work like this or do i need to specifically migrate my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In theory simply adding new fields could work without migrating,

Technically even in any SQLite database, you'd write the `alter table add column` statements yourself.

Realm of course is not SQLite, so it can be different.

> Does Realm work like this or do i need to specifically migrate my database?

Tricky question:

- if you are using RealmConfiguration, you need to add fields to the schema manually in a migration
- if you are using SyncConfiguration, then additive changes are applied automatically and the fields will be null, BUT destructive changes (removing fields, changing index, changing required, changing primary key) are disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to do this every time you add a new field. Otherwise, you will get an exepction- "RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is more than expected - expected X but was Y"

Comment: It's actually a bit more specific than that since Realm-Java 3.7.1